# jquery delete table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table

```
<table id="favoriteFoodTable">
    <th>
        Food Name:
    </th>
    <th>
        Restaurant Name:
    </th>
    <th>

    </th>
    <?php while ($row = $foods->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodName']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['restaurantName']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="deleteLink" href="" >delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I use this jquery function so when a user click on delete, the background of the row will change and the row then will delete

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoriteFoodTable .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
        var td = $(this).parent();
        var tr = td.parent();
        //change the background color to red before removing
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");

        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

just the background is changing but the row is not deleted, why? how to solve?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The row is deleted but as clicking makes you follow the link, it's immediately restored when the page is refreshed.

Add `return false;` or [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) at the end of the callback to prevent the default behavior :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoriteFoodTable .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
            tr.remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/umomoz/2/edit)

Note that I used `closest` for a more reliable code : if another element comes in between, the `tr` will still be found.

Comment: What do you mean ? Click on the "delete" : the row fades then is removed.

Answer (score 3):

What you forgot to do is to set hash in your link.
example:

```
<a class="deleteLink" href="" >delete</a>
```

should be

```
<a class="deleteLink" href="#" >delete</a>
```

or

```
return false;
```

at end of your

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoriteFoodTable .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
        ...
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option.

```
function DeleteRowOfProductTable(productID){
    $('#YourTableId tr').each(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row);
        var productLabelId =  $row.find('label[name*="Product_' + productID + '"]');

       var $productLabelIdValue = $productLabelId.text();
       if (parseInt(productID) == parseInt($productLabelIdValue))
       {
           $row.remove(); 
       }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 1 row in the table to be selected at a time

```
$("#data tr").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#data tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if(!selected)
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
tr.detach();
```

Worked for me!

Comment: please add more description to your answer